# EF6 excecute scalar function

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using entity framework 6 with databasefirst. Since hours I'm trying to find the right way to call a scalar valued function. Nothing works. I've try'ed 
-Database.SqlQuery
-Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
other things written in some articles - but i can't get the right result from the function :-c
Can anyone please give me some advice? I'm clueless...
Thanks
Boris

Comment: Maybe you can use this https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/

Comment: thank, i wil have a look at this